# Unable to get href of child element in Puppeteer js

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have the following element:

```
<li id="" class="search-item multi-items showClass inner-area" has-data="yes">  
 <ul class="">
<li class="description">
    <ul>
        <li class="title">
           
                            <a href="example.com/blahblah" style="color:#232323;">Blah blah</a>
```

The element is dynamically added, I wait for it like so:

```
await page.waitForSelector(".inner-area", {visible: true});
```

I then attempt to get the first element href like so:

```
const cardHref = await page.$eval(
              ".inner-area .description .title a",
              el => el.href);
```

This gives me an error:

```
failed to find element matching selector ".inner-area .description .title a"
```

I was assuming that this is how I nest the child elements.  I'm obviously doing something wrong.  How can I get that first element when it appears?

Comment: Have you tried `.inner-area > ul > .description > ul > .title > a`?

Comment: No I hadn't I'll try that.  I was assuming it would traverse but I'm obviously wrong @Jordy

Comment: @Jordy didn't work.

Comment: Please show the actual page. There are many things that could prevent this element from being selectable, from iframes to shadow DOMs to bot detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use my library that wraps puppeteer functions and makes them more stable.

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html)

In you case:

```js
import { getProperty } from 'bubanai-ng';

const cardHref = await getProperty('href', page, '.inner-area .description .title a');
```

or if you have href attribute

```js
    import { getAttribute } from 'bubanai-ng';

    const cardHref = await getAttribute('href', page, '.inner-area .description .title a');
```